# Unrecognised emulation mode: elf_i386 on MinGW32

Tags: c, assembly, linker, x86, osdev

I'm trying to make a kernel, and I cannot link the *C* output with the assembly. The `ld`. I'm getting the error:

> unrecognized emulation mode: elf_i386

I'm using Windows 10 professional with the MinGW32 and MSYS. The code I am using:

**link.ld**

```
/*
*  link.ld
*/
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
ENTRY(start)
SECTIONS
 {
   . = 0x100000;
   .text : { *(.text) }
   .data : { *(.data) }
   .bss  : { *(.bss)  }
 }
```

**kernel.c**

```
/*
*  kernel.c
*/
void kmain(void)
{
    const char *str = "my first kernel";
    char *vidptr = (char*)0xb8000;  //video mem begins here.
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int j = 0;

    /* this loops clears the screen
    * there are 25 lines each of 80 columns; each element takes 2 bytes */
    while(j < 80 * 25 * 2) {
        /* blank character */
        vidptr[j] = ' ';
        /* attribute-byte - light grey on black screen */
        vidptr[j+1] = 0x07;         
        j = j + 2;
    }

    j = 0;

    /* this loop writes the string to video memory */
    while(str[j] != '\0') {
        /* the character's ascii */
        vidptr[i] = str[j];
        /* attribute-byte: give character black bg and light grey fg */
        vidptr[i+1] = 0x07;
        ++j;
        i = i + 2;
    }
    return;
}
```

**kernel.asm**

```
;;kernel.asm
bits 32         ;nasm directive - 32 bit
section .text

global start
extern kmain            ;kmain is defined in the c file

start:
  cli           ;block interrupts
  mov esp, stack_space  ;set stack pointer
  call kmain
  hlt           ;halt the CPU

section .bss
resb 8192       ;8KB for stack
stack_space:
```

To Compile and link I use:

```
nasm -f elf32 kernel.asm -o kasm.o
gcc -m32 -c kernel.c -o kc.o
ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o
```

I'm Using:

- Gcc 4.8.1
- Ld 2.25.1
- Nasm 2.11.09rc1

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You left out a lot of information ... what commands you used to compile the c++ and the asm, what command you used to link, what's the version of `ld` and what emulations it supports, and last but not least, what output you expect. Obviously if you want elf output you need a toolchain that can do elf. The mingw tools are geared towards PE so that's probably your issue.

Comment: I Think There Is A Problem With Your Shift Key On Your Keyboard. If you could supply more details, we can assist you better.

Comment: There is the potential for a good question in here but you would need to show us your bootloader, your kernel, linker scripts and current commands you use to build your kernel. With that information it might become a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) have a much better chance of being answered.

Comment: I Inserted The Code Now!

Comment: @Razor: your edit was rolled back because it removed details from the question (e.g. Windows 10), and turned the filenames into whole sentences.  Reading more text to get the same information is less good.  Also, taking the error message out of the title is a critical mistake.  StackOverflow often shows lists of related questions in a sidebar where you can only see the title, so having specific titles is absolutely essential.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: No worries! I wasn't deliberately intending for that. I will definitely keep that in mind!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard MinGW/32 *LD* linker doesn't output *ELF* binaries. Preferably you would be using an i686 cross-compiler, but if you're not you may be able to get away with the tips below.

It appears you are using Arjun's [Let's Write a Kernel](http://arjunsreedharan.org/post/82710718100/kernel-101-lets-write-a-kernel) tutorial. If you are following that tutorial you have missed a step to make `kernel.asm` compatible with the *GRUB* boot loader and *QEMU*'s `-kernel` option. Before we start you should read the rest of the tutorial. The following code adds a Multiboot header to `kernel.asm` to make it GRUB compatible:

```
;;kernel.asm
bits 32         ;nasm directive - 32 bit
global entry
extern _kmain            ;kmain is defined in the c file

section .text
entry:  jmp start

        ;multiboot spec
        align 4
        dd 0x1BADB002            ;magic
        dd 0x00                  ;flags
        dd -(0x1BADB002 + 0x00)  ;checksum. m+f+c should be zero

start:
        cli           ;block interrupts
        mov esp, stack_space  ;set stack pointer
        call _kmain
        hlt           ;halt the CPU

section .bss
resb 8192       ;8KB for stack
stack_space:
```

Besides adding a header I've also put an `entry` label in the file and a `jmp start` to jump over the Multiboot header. I've done this to make it easy to set a breakpoint at 0x100000 in the future if you start debugging.

One other change is that on MinGW, *GCC* adds an underscore to function names by default. I've changed references to the *C* function `kmain` to `_kmain`. This differs from the Linux convention.

Since the entry point of our code is now `entry` instead of `start` I've modified `link.ld` to be:

```
/*
*  link.ld
*/
OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-i386)    
ENTRY(entry)

SECTIONS
 {
   . = 0x100000;
   .text : { *(.text) }
   .data : { *(.data) }
   .bss  : { *(.bss)  }
 }
```

Another important change in the file above is the usage of `OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-i386)` . This will output a Portable Executable Image (32-bit) rather than an *ELF* (which isn't supported).

In order to build the kernel and produce an *ELF* image from the *PEI-I386* we can use these commands:

```
nasm -f elf32 kernel.asm -o kasm.o
gcc -m32 -c kernel.c -o kc.o -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostdinc
ld -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o -build-id=none
objcopy -O elf32-i386 kernel kernel.elf
```

The *LD* command has been modified to not write out the build-id to the executable to avoid the Multiboot header from being shifted outside the first 8k of the executable. The *GCC* options have been modified to produce freestanding code (without the standard library and includes) using the options `-ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostdinc`.  We use `objcopy` to convert the *PEI-I386* file (`kernel`) to an *ELF32* image called `kernel.elf`. You will want to be using `kernel.elf` with *GRUB* and/or *QEMU*.

Comment: How does this compare to using `objcopy` on each of the `.o` files individually? (and then producing an ELF directly during the link)

Comment: @o11c if you mean using OBJCOPY on `.o` files to convert them to directly to binary format for use with a kernel?

Comment: From my (simple) experiments, you can use `gcc -m32 -c kernel.c -o kc-tmp.o; objcopy -O elf32-i386 kc-tmp.o kc.o` and then specify `OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)` in the link, but I don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: @o11c : Obcjopy is generally used to convert or change between different output. If you are on _GCC_ for Linux the default is already elf32-i386 so converting them to elf32-i386 wouldn't do much of anything. Are you on Linux or Windows? If making a kernel usually you compile things to object files, link them together and then use OBJCOPY to copy the resulting program to a binary format. You probably should consider asking that as a new question.

Comment: No, I'm referring to the same environment with MinGW but targetting baremetal. Remember that `objcopy` (and `libbfd` in general) works on all objects, including relocatables, executables, shared libraries, and coredumps.