# "ld: Unsupported PEI architecture: pei-i386" error when using LD

Tags: c, assembly, linker

I'm trying to assemble a C file and a ASM file together and somehow I get this `"ld: Unsupported PEI architecture: pei-i386"` error when using LD. I used [this tutorial](https://arjunsreedharan.org/post/82710718100/kernels-101-lets-write-a-kernel)) with some modified code from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687608/unrecognised-emulation-mode-elf-i386-on-mingw32)

Following the entire set of the files of interest

1) The main Assembly file

```
;;kernel.asm
bits 32         ;nasm directive - 32 bit
global entry
extern _kmain            ;kmain is defined in the c file

section .text
entry:  jmp start

        ;multiboot spec
        align 4
        dd 0x1BADB002            ;magic
        dd 0x00                  ;flags
        dd -(0x1BADB002 + 0x00)  ;checksum. m+f+c should be zero

start:
        cli           ;block interrupts
        mov esp, stack_space  ;set stack pointer
        call _kmain
        hlt           ;halt the CPU

section .bss
resb 8192       ;8KB for stack
stack_space:
```

2) The C file

```
/*
*   kernel.c
*/

void kmain(void)
{
    const char *str = "kernel 1.0";
    char *vidptr = (char*)0xb8000;  // video mem begins here
    unsigned int j = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    while(j < 80 * 25 * 2) {
        /* blank char */
        vidptr[j] = ' ';
        /* attr. byte - light gray on black screen */
        vidptr[j+1] = 0x07;
        j = j + 2;
    }

    j = 0;

    /* this loop writes the string into vram */
    while(str[j] != '\0') {
        /* the characters ASCII */
        vidptr[i] = str[j];
        /* atr. byte - give character black bg and light gray fg */
        vidptr[i + 1] = 0x07;
        ++j;
        i = i + 2;
    }
}
```

3) The Linker file

```
/*
*   link.ld
*/
OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-i386)
ENTRY(entry)

SECTIONS
 {
   . = 0x100000;
   .text : { *(.text) }
   .data : { *(.data) }
   .bss  : { *(.bss)  }
 }
```

4) a Batch file I made for simplifying the process to build it all. I'm using cygwin

```
@echo off

echo Building...
nasm -f elf32 kernel.asm -o kasm.o
echo ok
gcc -m32 -c kernel.c -o kc.o -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostdinc
echo ok
ld -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o -build-id=none
echo ok
objcopy -O elf32-i386 kernel kernel.elf
echo ok
echo Done.
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: I am confused, if everthing is elf, why do you use `pei-i386`?

Comment: In the original tutorial, it said in the link file at the place of pei-i386 that you had to use elf32-i386, and that did not work for me at all. When the batch file gets ran it outputs: 
`Building...
ok
ok
ld: Unsupported PEI architecture: pei-i386
ok
objcopy: error: the input file 'kernel' is empty
ok
Done.`

Comment: @Jester : because his linker apparently only generates WinPE executables (although it is able to read elf objects). Objcopy though is more universal and can convert to ELF. If an elf cross compiler/toolchain were being used this wouldn't be an issue of course. Using a native tool chain can lead to this kind of stuff.

Comment: What happens if you remove `OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-i386)` from your linker script?

Comment: Sorry I could not respond.
When I remove Output_Format from my linker script it returns:
`ld: i386 architecture of input file `kasm.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
ld: i386 architecture of input file `kc.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output`
@MichaelPetch

Comment: Alright, will be doing that
Results:
`$ ld -m mode
ld: unrecognised emulation mode: mode
Supported emulations: i386pep i386pe` @MichaelPetch

Comment: Make sure the `OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-i386)` line is removed from the linker script and then change your linker line to be `ld -m i386pe -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o -build-id=none` . What happens?

Comment: The batch script outputs:
`Building...
ok
ok
ok
ok
Done.`
with no errors. @MichaelPetch

Comment: Does the resulting executable work when loaded with GRUB?

Comment: @MichaelPetch It does, QEMU works fine with it the last time I used it